# how to add Existing files to the resource folder in Xcode4

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

like in finder I dragged some image files to the project now in Xcode how to add these image files in Xcode4 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add files using 'Add Files to' context menu. See the screenshot below.[image]
[image]

Comment: if I am doing the same it not asking copy option like Xcode3.2

Comment: it does, I've added another screenshot to the answer, see the checkbox marked in red